# CASE statement in mySQL, comparison operator

Tags: mysql, case

I don't understand why this query does not work.  It hits a file with about 15,000 records.

```
SELECT emp_id, check_date, case when check_amount <= 300 then check_amount 
end as below_300   FROM `payments`
```

It should return only those checks that are less than 300 but it returns the entire file all-- 15,000 records.  It returns the correct emp_id, check_date but a 'null' in the check amount.

I am using a CASE statement because I want to run several thresholds for checks lower than certain amounts ($300, $1,000, $2,000 etc).

Thanks!

Comment: It returns all of the records because there isn't a where clause. Also, since the calculation will appear on rows where the check_amount is greater than 300, you need an else expression. Do you want a list of checks, or a count of checks with certain ranges?

Comment: show your result and desire result. so i can help you

Comment: You need a where clause.. `SELECT emp_id, check_date, case WHERE check_amount ...` Also, as mentioned, what is the desired result set you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's two possible answers:

If you want to run individual queries for each range:

```
SELECT 
    emp_id, 
    check_date, 
    check_amount
FROM `payments`
WHERE check_amount <= 300
```

If you want summary information on the groups you mention.

```
SELECT 
    `emp_id`,
    `check_date`,
    sum(if(`check_amount` <= 300, 1, 0)) as `num_under_300`,
    sum(if(`check_amount` <= 300, `check_amount`, 0)) as `sum_under_300`,
    sum(if(`check_amount` > 300 AND `check_amount` <= 1000, 1, 0)) as `num_under_1000`,
    sum(if(`check_amount` > 300 AND `check_amount` <= 1000, `check_amount`, 0)) as `sum_under_1000`,
    sum(if(`check_amount` > 1000 AND `check_amount` <= 2000, 1, 0)) as `num_under_2000`,
    sum(if(`check_amount` > 1000 AND `check_amount` <= 2000, `check_amount`, 0)) as `sum_under_2000`,
    sum(if(`check_amount` > 2000, 1, 0)) as `num_over_2000`,
    sum(if(`check_amount` > 2000, `check_amount`, 0)) as `sum_over_2000`
FROM `payments`
GROUP BY `emp_id`,`check_date`
```

Comment: Thanks Sloan - the first approach does work.  But when I run the second, I get an error message = #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`check_amount` <= 300 then 1 else 0 end) as `num_under_300`,
    sum(if `check_a' at line 4;   Just FYI I am running Server version: 5.5.47-MariaDB and phpmyadmin Version information: 4.4.15.5

Comment: Sorry about that. I changed the _end_ to _end if_. If that doesn't work, I can change it to the **if** function. I went ahead and changed them to use the __if()__ function.

Comment: Hi Sloan, thanks again - I am not sure I follow though - where should I introduce 'end if' Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to. I edited the answer above to correct the functions used.